# How to use rpartition to split the string with backward slashes

Tags: python

I need to print the last string which is "foo" here, it's an error with no escape character and wrong result with escape character.

```
>>> str1='\\a\b\c\foo'
>>> print str1.rpartition('\')[1]
File "<stdin>", line 1
print str1.rpartition('\')[1]
                            ^
SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal
>>> print str1.rpartition('\\')[1]
\
>>>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two mistakes:

First of all, there's no `foo` in `\\a\b\c\foo`. Why? Because `\f` is a form feed character. You can either escape the backslash with another backslash `\\\\a\\b\\c\\foo` or use a raw string `str1=r'\\a\b\c\foo'`.

Secondly, `rpartition` returns the left part of the string, the separator itself, and the right part of the string. So `str1.rpartition('\\')[1]` gives you the separator. Use `str1.rpartition('\\')[2]` to get the result you want.

Comment: Thanks, I just started doing Python, switched from Perl :)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have:

```
s = r'\\a\b\c\foo'
```

You need:

```
s.rsplit('\\', 1)[-1]
```

If your backslashes are messed up, see the other answers (no need to repeat those caveats here).

Answer (score 0):

You need the third element of the partition tuple:

```
>>> str1=r'a\b\c\foo'
>>> str1.rpartition('\\')
('a\\b\\c', '\\', 'foo')
>>> str1.rpartition('\\')[2]
'foo'
```

Answer (score 0):

In you print line the '\' character is escaping the second `'` .  It can't parse the line of code becasue to to the compiler it looks like the line doesn't end.
it looks like this to the compiler `')[1]` It things the quote mark is part of the string. you need to add a second '\' to escape the first one. try this:

```
print str1.rpartition('\\')[1]
```